# Converter código de VB para C# que transforma caracteres em números

Tags: c#, string, vb.net, char

Tenho este código em VB e preciso converter para C#.

```
Public Function eNumero(s As String) As Boolean
    If s = "" Then
        eNumero = False
    Else
        eNumero = Asc(s) >= Asc("0") And Asc(s) <= Asc("9")
    End If
End Function
```

Já tentei converter, mas não funciona. O problema esta na função ASC.

```
public bool eNumero(string s)
{
    if (s == "")
        eNumero = false;
    else
        eNumero = Strings.Asc(s) >= Strings.Asc("0") & Strings.Asc(s) <= Strings.Asc("9");
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisando seu código fica fácil de entender que função `bool eNumero(string s)` é uma função lógica que recebe uma string como entrada devolve o valor lógico `true` indicando se o primeiro caractere da string de entrada é um número entre 0 e 9, caso o contrário a função retorna `false`. Para isso a função obtém o código ASCII do primeiro caractere da string de entrada, por meio da função do nativa do Visual Basic [`String.Asc(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8), e então verifica se mesmo está contido no intervalo da tabela ASCII que compreende os números entre 0 e 9.

Vejo duas possibilidades de solução. Uma é continuar usando a função do Visual Basic [`String.Asc(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8) dentro de um código C# ou outra solução seria abandonar a função `bool eNumero(string s)` em prol de uma solução já pronta e empacotada dentro do .Net Framework.

**Para usar as funções nativas do visual basic** adicione o namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic` a seu projeto.

Vá e em Solution Explorer->Add Reference adicione os assemblies `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility` e `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.Data`.

No seu código adicione a clausula using `Microsoft.VisualBasic;`.

*Nota: em C# use o operador `return` quando quiser retornar o um valor.*

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

public class Program
{ 

    public static bool eNumero(string s)
    {    
        if (s == "") return false;
        else return Strings.Asc(s) >= Strings.Asc("0") && Strings.Asc(s) <= Strings.Asc("9");        
    }

    public static void Main()
    { 

        Console.WriteLine(eNumero("2365"));
    }
}
```

A outra alternativa é a **solução fornecida pelo Framework**, como já disse, o consiste em abandonar a função `eNumero` e utilizar ou função [`Single.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) ou dependendo de suas necessidades apena o [`Int32.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8). O que vejo vantagem pois a as funções do framework analisam em uma única passagem uma string para verificar se a string de entrada é um número ou não, enquanto a função `bool eNumero(string s)` faz a verificação caractere por caractere e não é capaz de analisar estruturas numéricas mais complexas.

A função [`Single.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) converte a representação da string em um número de ponto flutuante com precisão simples equivalente o retornando um valor lógico indicando se a conversão foi bem sucedida ou não.

Já a função [`Int32.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) converte a representação da string em um número de inteiro de 32bits  o retornando um valor lógico indicando se a conversão foi bem sucedida ou não.

**Exemplos de uso tanto de [`Single.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) e de [`Int32.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       float f;
       int i;
       Console.WriteLine( (Single.TryParse("143.56", out f)) ? 
                                              (f + 102).ToString() : 
                                                   "não é um número"
                         );

       Console.WriteLine( (Single.TryParse("Teste", out f)) ? 
                                              (f + 102).ToString() : 
                                                   "não é um número"
                         );

       Console.WriteLine( (Int32.TryParse("2143", out i)) ?
                                          (i + 792).ToString() :
                                              "não é um número"
                         );
       // Nesse caso não trata-se de um zero e sim da letra O.
       Console.WriteLine( (Int32.TryParse("18O", out i)) ?
                                          (i + 792).ToString() :
                                              "não é um número"
                         );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O código VB é ruim. Não é possível converter adequadamente um texto inteiro para sua representação numérica ASCII. É possível fazer isto com um caractere. Há garantias que o parâmetro `string` será sempre um caractere? Se é, por que não vem um tipo `char`? Mas vamos lá:

```
public static bool eNumero(string s) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) return false;
    return (int)s[0] >= (int)'0' && (int)s[0] <= (int)'9';
}
```

Notei outros problemas. A verificação "se é vazio" está errada e pode ter problemas dependendo do que venha. E não precisa de variável, pode encerrar a execução ali mesmo se for inválido. Eu garanti que pega só o primeiro caractere e faço um *cast* nesse caractere de forma simples. Usei o operador `&&` que é o correto para este tipo de verificação. Usando o *cast* em literal é mais eficiente que fazer uma conversão.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(eNumero(""));
        WriteLine(eNumero("a"));
        WriteLine(eNumero("5"));
    }
    public static bool eNumero(string s) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) return false;
        return (int)s[0] >= (int)'0' && (int)s[0] <= (int)'9';
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XZPHGf). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vkxM5J). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CompareChar.cs).

Comment: se eu fizer apenas `(int)s[0] >= (int)'0'`, `eNumero("a")` será positivo. Pode explicar?

Comment: Não tenho ideia do que está falando

Comment: Aqui: `return (int)s[0] >= (int)'0';// && (int)s[0] <= (int)'9'`;

Comment: Ainda não sei o que quer dizer com isso. Se tem uma nova pergunta sobre o assunto, abra um novo *post*, caso contrário precisa dizer o que está querendo.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira não é necessário fazer `(int)'3'` quando você simplesmente pode colocar o `3`.

Comment: @CypherPotato isto está errado.

Comment: @Maniero a conversão não daria o mesmo sentido?

Comment: @Maniero agora que vi que isso retorna o código unicode do caractere, e não a conversão numérica em si. Realmente está errado.

Comment: @CypherPotato exatamente o que percebi, por isso os comentários, como estou estudando C# achei pertinente questionar para ampliar o conhecimento!